# Rmarkdown error: Invalid nesting of html_preserve directives

Tags: html, r, rstudio, knitr, r-markdown

When I try a bunch of chunks in RStudio I get the following error in RStudio:

```
 |.................................................................| 100%
 ordinary text without R code


 output file: relatorio1.knit.md

 Error in extract(input_str) : Invalid nesting of html_preserve directives
  Calls: <Anonymous> ... <Anonymous> -> base -> extract_preserve_chunks -> extract
```

I really could not identify what is going on since the debugger tells me nothing and the code runs until 100%, but it simply does not generate the html file as it was supposed to.

I see that this error comes from htmltools package code (see https://github.com/rstudio/htmltools/blob/master/R/tags.R), which says:

```
# Sanity check.
 if (any(preserve_level < 0) || tail(preserve_level, 1) != 0) {
stop("Invalid nesting of html_preserve directives")
}
```

Unfortunately I cannot provide the whole Rmd file since it is work related, but generic comments on this issue are welcome.

Thanks.

Edit: I tried to circumvent the problem by isolating datatables (package DT) that were not working. I am using data.table's fread funtion, but I also tried readr and base data.table. I also tried to load data directly from source (source file generates data). When I try to knit it, I still get the above error. Never had any problem with these functions before.

I try the following code:

````
---
title: "Title"
output: flexdashboard::flex_dashboard
---
```{r setup}
require(DT)
require(flexdashboard)
require(htmltools)
require(htmlwidgets)
require(readr)
require(data.table)
source("sourcefile.R")
a <- fread("perfectlynormaldata.txt")
b <- a[,1:10]
```

Flexdashboard Storyboard {.storyboard}
=========================================

### Text Text

```{r datatable not running}
datatable(b)
```
````

Edit 2: I could render the datatable after limiting the length of a string variable with substr. I don't know if it was supposed to happen.

Final Edit: I could solve definitely the issue by removing certain characters that appear in the problematic variable as "\032".

Comment: You need to try to find the chunk(s) or text that are causing the problem and work on reproducing it. Posting the whole Rmd file is a terrible idea - I'm glad you won't do that. But if you delete the last half of the file, is there still a problem? What about the first half? Then find the right quarter, then the right eighth, then find the smallest code you can that still reproduces the problem. My guess is by now you'll have solved the problem yourself, but if not please make a post with some more details and the smallest possible code you can find that illustrates the problem.

Comment: Thanks Gregor, unfortunately I still could not solve this issue. Please see edit. Have a happy new year.

Comment: Wow, this is much better! Even now though, there's a lot of extra stuff. How many lines can you delete and still see the problem? And this isn't reproducible without `sourcefile.R` and `perfectlynormaldata.txt` files. If you delete the lines that use those does the problem remain? You load `readr` but don't use it at all, can you delete that line? What about `htmlwidgets`? Either you can do it once for everyone, or everyone who tries to answer your question will have to do it themself... (or we just assume the problem in in that `.R` file your source without sharing)

Comment: I will try to edit the file and post it. I suspect there is something wrong when I subset the data (weird). I load all those packages because they are used later in the (full) code.

Comment: Again, posting the file isn't what I'm asking for. Delete *as much as you can*, hopefully you'll end up with a few lines that can just be included in the chunk rather than posted separately.

Comment: I was able to remedy the issue by limiting the length of a string variable (to 52 characters, don't ask me why). I had to break the code into minimal pieces so I could identify the problem, which was a tedious but necessary process.

Comment: Glad you worked it out! That's what debugging is...

Comment: Got the same error solved by removing special characters in a plotly chart